# Compare two files and print unmatched lines

Tags: shell, text-processing, diff

I have two files with the below data; I need the difference between two files.

I tried with `diff` but it also shows line which are common in the two files: `(22372 Dec 4 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/new.txt)`.

First file: (multiple data exists in the same way in file 1)

```
22677 Dec 4 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/abc.txt

22372 Dec 4 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/new.txt
```

Second file: (multiple data exists in the same way in file 2).

```
22372 Dec 4 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/new.txt

22677 Dec 3 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/abc.txt

12344 Dec 10 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/abc/.../test.txt
```

I need the below output:

```
22677 Dec 3 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/abc.txt

12344 Dec 10 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/abc/.../test.txt
```

Answer (score 19):

This seems like a perfect opportunity to use comm.

From the GNU coreutils manual page (v8.30):

```
With  no  options,  produce  three-column  output.  Column one contains
lines unique to FILE1, column two contains lines unique to  FILE2,  and
   column three contains lines common to both files.

   -1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)

   -2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)

   -3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)
```

Using this information, we can remove the lines unique `file1` as well as the lines present in both files.

```
$ comm -1 -3 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
12344 Dec 10 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/abc/.../test.txt
22677 Dec 3 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/abc.txt
```

-1 and -3 removes all lines unique to file 1 and all lines common to both.

Because of the sort, it will change the order of the output but that doesn't seem to be a consideration based on the question.

If the input is already sorted, you can skip the sorts yielding

```
$ comm -1 -3 file1 file2
```

Comment: from `comm` man page:

-1     suppress column 1 (lines unique to FILE1)
-2     suppress column 2 (lines unique to FILE2)
-3     suppress column 3 (lines that appear in both files)

Answer (score 4):

Use `diff -u file1 file2  | sed -nr 's/^+([^+].*)/\1/p'`

Output:

> 22677 Dec 3 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/abc.txt
>   12344 Dec 10 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/abc/.../test.txt

If you need the blank line between them, use
`diff -u file1 file2 | sed -nr 's/^+([^+].*)/\1\n/p'`

Output:

> 22677 Dec 3 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/new/abc.txt
>
> 12344 Dec 10 15:36 /opt/apache-tomcat-6.0.36/webapps/abc/.../test.txt

Comment: I tried with this  diff --suppress-common-lines file1 file2 but still it shows the common files

Comment: Updated and tested. Is this the output you need?

Comment: When there are 2-3 lines in each file, it works fine. I have multiple lines in both files (around 4000 lines) and in that case it's not working. Same line exists in both files but not in same order and i need to exclude them in ouput.

Comment: Thanks... grep -xvFf and  comm -23 <(sort file1.txt) <(sort file2.txt) resolves the issue

Comment: If lines can exist on another oder, sort the two file using `sort` before applying the above command